# Allow entry in only one input field in form

Tags: jquery, html

I have form that has around 20-25 fields. I need to implement following requirement

Out of all the fields there are 4 particular fields that need to have following validation

- If none of them is populated then highlight the fields and show error Atleast one is required
- If more than one is populated then highlight the fields and show error Only one is required.

I am getting the selectors of those fields from JSON file. Here is an example of how the field HTML will look like

```
<input type="text" name="s_18_1_2_0" value="" aria-labelledby="DC2_AP2-T_Transport_speed_-_Business_Label" aria-label="AP2-T Transport speed - Business" style="height: 30px; width: 140px;" maxlength="250" class="siebui-input-align-left ui-autocomplete-input siebui-input-popup undefined" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" tabindex="0" aria-readonly="false" aria-describedby=" s_18_1_2_0_icon">

<input type="text" name="s_18_1_8_0" value="" aria-labelledby="DC2_Pair_in_Operator_Label" aria-label="Pair in Operator trunk" style="height: 30px; width:150px;" maxlength="250" tabindex="0" class="siebui-input-align-left dc2-invalid" aria-readonly="false" title="Pair in Operator trunk is required field">
```

I have been able to write the following code to select all the fields

```
for(var i = 0; i < param.length; i++){
    selector = param[i].replace(/\s/g,"_") + "_Label";
    input ? input += ", input[aria-labelledby=" + selector + "]" : input = "input[aria-labelledby=" + selector + "]";

    $(input).each(function(e){
        //if($(this).val() != "")
        SiebelJS.Log(this);
    });

}
```

This code selects the fields on which I need to perform validation but the main difficulty is highlight part so I need selectors of the fields that have failed validation. Can I use filter in addition to the each?

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: yes ,please use filter

Answer (score 0):

First declare a class in you style:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
        border:1px solid red;
        background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Then try the following code:

```
   var maxLimit = 0;
        var minLimit = 0;
        $(input).each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length < 1) {
                minLimit++;
            } else {
                maxLimit++;
            }
        });
        if (minLimit == $(input).length) {
            $(input).addClass("error");
            alert("Message for required field");
        }
        else if (maxLimit > 1) {
            $(input).addClass("error");
            alert("Message to fill only 1 input value, not more");
        }
        else if (minLimit != $(input).length && maxLimit < 2) {
            $(input).removeClass("error");
        }
```

This may help you.